# Reflections in locally presentable categories

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, locally-presentable-categories

In [this](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107343/ArchMath_025-1989-1_12.pdf) paper,
-4th line in the first paragraph on the (first) page 89,

**then each full subcategory of $\cal H$ closed under limits ...**

should or should not the word **reflective** be present:

**then each full *reflective* subcategory of H closed under limits ...** ?

I think that the word "reflective" is omitted by mistake, but I'm not sure.

It seems strange to me that if $\cal H$ is a locally presentable category
then each full (but possibly non-reflective) subcategory of $\cal H$ closed under limits is closed
under $\alpha$-filtered colimits for some regular cardinal $\alpha$.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the reference mentioned in that sentence ?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I have managed to upload that reference number [9] [here](http://leteckaposta.cz/498040413) but I cannot locate in it that mentioned property. Could you please determine the relevant page for me?

Comment: Is it not implied by Theorems 3 and 6 ?

Answer (score 1):

The word "reflective" can be left out, since it is implied by the other properties. We are talking here about a statement that is equivalent to Vopěnka's principle, which is a very strong large cardinal axiom. It can be stated in multiple equivalent ways (see e.g. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s+principle) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s_principle) for a few quick examples). On of these ways is the sentence you refer to in the paper.

So why can we leave out "reflective" in this particular statement? There is also a *weak* Vopěnka's principle, which is of course implied by Vopěnka's principle. The weak Vopěnka's principle is equivalent to:

> For every locally presentable category $\mathcal{C}$, every full subcategory $\mathcal{D} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ which is closed under limits is a reflective subcategory.

This is Theorem 2.7 on the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Vop%C4%9Bnka%27s+principle) I linked before. It can also be found as Theorem 6.22 in the book *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories* by J. Adámek and J. Rosický (well, the direction we are interested in, the other direction is Example 6.23). The entire chapter 6 in that book is dedicated to Vopěnka's principle, so it might be worth a look.